# How to read JSON body from Akka HTTP POST request and send the final response as JSON array

Tags: scala, http, akka, akka-http

I am new to akka http. I have created a program to make post request using http as follow -

```
object MainController {


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val serverSource = Http().bind(interface = "localhost", port = 9000)

    val requestHandler: HttpRequest => HttpResponse = {
      case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/welcome"), _, _, _) =>
        HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(
          ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
          "<html><body>Welcome to API Application</body></html>"))


      case HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/parseData"), _, entity: HttpEntity, _) =>

// Here Need to read request body which is in json format
        println("1 " + new String(entity.getDataBytes()))
        println("2 " + entity.getDataBytes())
// here need to do some calculations and again construct array of json response and send as HttpResponse
        HttpResponse(entity = "PONG!")

      case r: HttpRequest =>
        r.discardEntityBytes() // important to drain incoming HTTP Entity stream
        HttpResponse(404, entity = "Unknown resource!")
    }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandleSync(requestHandler, "localhost", 9000)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done

  }
}
```

As i have mentioned in above code inside "Post" request that I need to read the request body data which is array of json and do some calculations and finally send the processed array of json to HTTPResponse. Tried even High level API as well but it is again getting stuck in Marshalling. can anyone please explain or help me in this.

I have tried another approach as follows -

```
object MainController {

  // needed to run the route
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  final case class hexRecord(hexstring: String)
  final case class DeviceData(hexData: List[hexRecord])
  // formats for unmarshalling and marshalling

  implicit val contentFormat = jsonFormat1(hexRecord)
  implicit val dataFormat = jsonFormat1(DeviceData)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

    val requestBody = List.empty[Map[String, Any]]
    val route: Route =
      concat(
        get {
          path("welcome"){
          complete("Welcome to Parsing Application")}
        },
        post {
          path("parseDeviceData") {
            entity(as[DeviceData]) { data => {
              val result = data.hexData.map(row => {
                val parseData = ParserManager(Hex.decodeHex(row.hexstring.replaceAll("\\s", "").toCharArray))
               val jsonString = Serialization.writePretty(parseData)
                jsonString

              }).toArray 

              complete(result)
            }
            }
          }
        }
      )

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 9000)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:9000/")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
  }
}
```

This result is fine here but I am getting escape characters in output -

```
[
    " {\n  \"totalsize\" : 128,\n  \"devicetypeuno\" : \"2\"} ",
    " {\n  \"totalsize\" : 128,\n  \"devicetypeuno\" : \"2\"} "
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using following approach -

```
   case HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/decodedata"), _, entity, _) =>
        val chunk = Unmarshal(entity).to[List[DataChunk]]
        val deviceData = Await.result(chunk, 1.second)
        implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
        val resp = deviceData
          .map(data =>
            Serialization.write(ParserManager(Hex.decodeHex(data.rawData.replaceAll("\\s", "").toCharArray)))
          ).mkString

        HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, resp))



  case class DataChunk(rawData: String)

  object DataChunk {
    implicit val dataChunkJsonFormat: RootJsonFormat[DataChunk] = jsonFormat1(DataChunk.apply)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sample program that reads an array of json values and returns a new json back.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.util.Timeout
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpcirce.FailFastCirceSupport
import io.circe.generic.semiauto
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.io.StdIn

object WebServer3 extends FailFastCirceSupport {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    implicit val timeout: Timeout = 2.seconds
    case class Zoo(foo: String, bar: String)
    case class DoneZoo(message: String)
    implicit val zooDecoder: Decoder[Zoo] = semiauto.deriveDecoder[Zoo]
    implicit val zooEncoder: Encoder[Zoo] = semiauto.deriveEncoder[Zoo]
    implicit val doneDecoder: Decoder[DoneZoo] = semiauto.deriveDecoder[DoneZoo]
    implicit val doneEnecoder: Encoder[DoneZoo] =
      semiauto.deriveEncoder[DoneZoo]

    val route = path("parseData") {
      entity(as[List[Zoo]]) { zoo =>
        zoo.foreach(println)
        complete(DoneZoo(zoo.foldLeft("") {
          case (agg, el) => agg + el.bar + el.foo + ";"
        }))
      }
    }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine()
    val _ = bindingFuture.flatMap(_.unbind())
  }
}
```

The json is defined with the help of case classes and [circe semi auto derivation](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/semiauto-derivation.html). This creates Encoder/Decoder classes for json conversion. You have to convert these types into Akka specific ones used for entity marsharling and this is done implicitly with the help of de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpcirce.FailFastCirceSupport.

After this, you can use [akka route dsl](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/overview.html) to define your http routes. `entity(as[List[Zoo]])` will read http body as json and return back `List[Zoo]`

You can test this app with the help of `curl`

```
curl -v -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '[{"foo": "Foo", "bar": "Bar"}]' http://localhost:8080/parseData

Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /parseData HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 30
>
* upload completely sent off: 30 out of 30 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: akka-http/10.1.7
< Date: Tue, 15 Oct 2019 08:46:56 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 18
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"message":"DONE"}* Closing connection 0
```

EDIT:

Json serialisation must be left to be handled by akka in directives `entity(as[])` for request and `complete` for responses. Do not create JSON manually.

Comment: val route = path("parseData") {
      entity(as[List[Zoo]]) { zoo =>
        zoo.foreach(println)
        complete(DoneZoo("DONE"))
      }
    }
Here you are printing zoo.foreach but i need to extract each element do some calculation and finally return array of json in complete . Right now you have hardcoded DoneZoo("done") but here i need to send processed json.

Comment: I don't know what kind of processing you need to do. Thus it just prints it. You can use scala collections api like `fold` or `map` on `zoo` and do any calculation or transformations you need

Comment: Ivan your suggestion worked , now its just I'am getting escape characters in output but in intellij console its fine, coming proper , on postman it is showing issue. Can you please suggest how to overcome with it. please see my ques i have edited new approach

Comment: Ivan , as per your code for  input as [{"foo": "10","bar":"20"},{"foo":"30","bar":"30"}] I am getting output as {
    "message": "2010;3030;"
} when id concating values , which completly changing the content.

Comment: Yes, it shows you that you can produce responses based on requests. Just apply business logic you need instead of `DoneZoo(zoo.foldLeft("") {
          case (agg, el) => agg + el.bar + el.foo + ";"
        })`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling._
import spray.httpx.marshalling._
import spray.http._
import HttpCharsets._
import MediaTypes._

case class Person(name: String, firstName: String, age: Int)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val PersonFormat = jsonFormat3(Person)
}

import MyJsonProtocol._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.util._

val bob = Person("Bob", "Parr", 32)
val body = HttpEntity(
  contentType = ContentType(`application/json`, `UTF-8`),
  string =
    """|{
       |  "name": "Bob",
       |  "firstName": "Parr",
       |  "age": 32
       |}""".stripMarginWithNewline("\n")
)

marshal(bob) === Right(body)
body.as[Person] === Right(bob)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but in my case my case class have more than 100 columns and with sbt I cannot go with case class as it gives memoryoverflow error. So , need something dynamic itself to convert my entire response into json without mapping to case class like we do using Serialization which converts Map[String,Any] to respective JSON.

Comment: But I think in anyway you will have to save your response somewhere before sending it back? right then why not case classes? you can have case classes of case class to save 100 columns and I don't think for these many columns it's gonna give memoryoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just like `jsonFormat1[DeviceData]` and `as` combination is helping you convert a JSON string to DeviceData object, you can use the same technique in the other direction to convert your result to JSON, without manually marshaling the output.

```
implicit val parseDataJsonFormat = jsonFormatn[ParserManager]
// You should replace jsonFormatn with appropriate number based on the number of fields in ParserManager.
```

```
val result = data.hexData.map(row => {
          ParserManager(Hex.decodeHex(row.hexstring.replaceAll("\\s", "").toCharArray))
        }
    )
```

Comment: What if the value of "n" is dynamic ? like the result set can have different no of key value pairs on respective request. I have around 100 keys but it is dynamic so how should I handle that ?